# What does call stack results in error reports mean?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the Go 1.13 error handling from https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors?tab=doc#pkg-overview but could not get the meaning of the following description:

```
which when applied recursively up the call stack results in error reports without context or debugging information
```

Could someone please provide an example in corresponding to sentence above.

What is the advantage of error in Go 1.13 in comparing to old style error handling?

Comment: It describes the "traditional" way of error handling in Go. Say you have function `f1`, which call `f2`, which calls `f3a` and `f3b`, now `f3a` returns an error to `f2` and the "traditional" way is to just pass the error up the call stack, meaning `f2` just passes the error to `f1`, but now, becuase there's no context `f1` doesn't know why `f2` failed, was it because `f3a` or `f3b` or because of something else? The next section in the documentation describes how you can remedy this by adding a context to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the next section on the page could potentially enlighten you.
The "err" being returned recursively, is the error being propagated to the caller, ultimately reaching the top level caller (main for instance), this is what this means.

Now if the cause or detail of the error is not specified, it is going to be very hard to know how to fix it. Providing context, ensures that the emitter of the error can be easily identified.